# How to set sync_nodes_timeout?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am trying to connect nodes in cluster using:

```
:net_adm.world()
```

But, in this way, as erlang will read the `.hosts.erlang` how would I set sync nodes time outs?

Comment: https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/01/28/running-elixir-and-phoenix-projects-on-a-cluster-of-nodes explains how to do it

Comment: I've read that blog, but I need to use `:net_adm.world()` as in here https://johnhamelink.com/2016/03/03/elixir-and-ec2